# Formatting value of year from SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert the current date into one of the columns of my table.  I am using the following:

```
to_date(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

This is working great, but it is displaying the year as '0014'.  Is there some way that I can get the year to display as '2014'?

Comment: inserting it as `TRUNC(sysdate)` would do. Date actually doesn't have a format internally. `TRUNC()` actualy will trim of the time element in the current date time. and just return today's date with time as `00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to_date is used to convert a string to a date ... try to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') to convert a date to a string.

Comment: I cast to char and then to to date.  The year now displays the way I wanted. `to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 3):

Inserting it as `TRUNC(sysdate)` would do. Date actually doesn't have a format internally as it is DataType itself. TRUNC() actualy will just trim the time element in the current date time and return today's date with time as 00:00:00

To explain what happened in your case.

say ur `NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YY-MM-DD"`

The Processing will  be like below

```
select  to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') from  dual;
```

**Output:**

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')

January, 22 0014 00:00:00+0000
```

`2014` - gets reduced to `'14'` in first `to_char()` and later while converted again as `YYYY`.. it wil be treated as `0014` as the current century detail is last!

Comment: This looks promising, but I had already incorporated another solution.

Comment: I see your comment above, TRUNC() does the same in a single function call. Anyway no problems!

Answer (score 2):

The to_date function converts a string to a date.  SYSDATE is already a date, so what this will do is to first convert SYSDATE to a string, using the session's date format as specified by NLS settings, and then convert that string back to date, using your specified date format (yyyy-mm-dd).  That may or may not give correct results, depending on the session's NLS date settings.

The simple and correct solution is to skip the to_date from this and use SYSDATE directly.

Comment: Converting SYSDATE to a string will use the session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, not the "default date format of the database".  It's likely if the clients are all in the same geographic region that they'll all have the same `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` but if you have clients in the US and clients in Eurpoe, it is highly likely that you'll have different settings on different clients.

Answer (score -6):

Try this to_date(SYSDATE, 'dd-mm-yy')